# Dragging and dropping incorrect item from array

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to follow the vue-draggable docs to create draggable lists but when I drag/drop an item, a different one is being moved. For example, if I drag `standard1` into the `Term2` list, `standard2` ends up on the second list. What's going on here?

```
data(){
  return {
    terms: [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Term1",
        "term_standards": [
          {"id": 1, "label": "standard1"},
          {"id": 2, "label": "standard2"},
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Term2",
        "term_standards": [
          {"id": 3, "label": "standard3"},
          {"id": 4, "label": "standard4"},
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}


<draggable
  v-model="terms[0].term_standards"
  class="dragArea"
  :options="{group:'ITEMS'}"
  :key="terms[0].id">
    {{ terms[0].label }}
  <li
    v-for="item in terms[0].term_standards"
    :key="item.id">
      {{ item.label }}
  </li>
</draggable>

<draggable
  v-model="terms[1].term_standards"
  class="dragArea"
  :options="{group:'ITEMS'}"
  :key="terms[1].id">
    {{ terms[1].label }}
  <li
    v-for="item in terms[1].term_standards"
    :key="item.id">
      {{ item.label }}
  </li>
</draggable>
```

Comment: When you inspect the dom elements, you should see that 1) missing `ul` element around the `<li>`. You can solve this by adding `element="ul"` to the `<draggable>` 2) `{{ terms[0].label }}` and `{{ terms[0].label }}` should be outside of `<draggable>`

Comment: I've updated my comment

Answer (score 0):

When the template is rendered, you are missing `ul` around the `li` elements.

Also, `{{ terms[0].label }` and `{{ terms[1].label }` should be placed outside of `<draggable>` element.

Your template should look like this

```html
{{ terms[0].label }}
<draggable
  element="ul"
  v-model="terms[0].term_standards"
  class="dragArea"
  :options="{group:'ITEMS'}"
>
  <li
    v-for="item in terms[0].term_standards"
    :key="item.id">
      {{ item.label }}
  </li>
</draggable>

{{ terms[1].label }}
<draggable
  element="ul"
  v-model="terms[1].term_standards"
  class="dragArea"
  :options="{group:'ITEMS'}"
>
  <li
    v-for="item in terms[1].term_standards"
    :key="item.id">
      {{ item.label }}
  </li>
</draggable>
```